# Trickle ICE and two peers on the same internal network

Tags: webrtc, stun

I noticed that if SDP sets icepolicy to trickle (a=ice-options:trickle) and the two peers are on the same internal network, the ICE agents do not generate Server Reflexive candidates and in fact no attempt is made to get server reflexive candidates. That appears to be the logical right decision but is the very definition of trickle ice not intended to gather ALL candidates, even if it is obvious that the first one will ultimately get nominated/selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome stops gathering candidates when it find a writeable candidate pair. That is somewhat understandable, since it would otherwise gather a relay candidate (which consumes resources) and then immediately deallocate it.